# Variable in Backbone.js view attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, attributes, underscore.js

I'm trying to achieve to render a block of HTML by using a model's attribute as a variable in a view.

```
App = Backbone.Model.extend({
        contentType: "text"
        });

AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        ContentTpl: _.template( $('#slide-'+this.model.get('contentType')).html() ),

        render: function(){
             $('#wrapper').html( this.ContentTpl() );    
        }
        });

var app = new App();
var appView = new AppView({model: app});
appView.render();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="slide-text">
   <p>This is a test</p>
</scrip>
```

But this results in an error...

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

You defined your view wrong.

you have

```
AppView = Backbone.Model.extend({
```

it should be

```
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
```

and, you cannot evaluate this.model before view is initialized,  do the following instead:

```
ContentTpl: function() {
   return _.template( $('#slide-'+ this.model.contentType).html() );
},
```

and , contentType is not a model attribute, it's an attribute on the model object, you cannot use get().

to define it as a model attribute you have to either define it as a default value in the model, or pass it when you instantiate an object:

```
var app = new App({contentType: 'text'});
```

or

```
App = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
     "contentType": "text"
  }
});
```

Comment: sry, i forgot that in my post. but of course, i had ` this.ContentTpl()` in my code. I edited my first post

Comment: what really behind this is, that when you define the view by doing AppView = Backbone.View.extend({})... javascript is gonna evaluate every attribute you defined in AppView object. (It's gonna try to run _.template(...) ) You will ge the error even before you actually instantiate a view since this.model is not available. If you define it as a function, javascript knows ContentTpl is a function, and it's not gonna run it until you tell it to.

Comment: Your code results in a jQuery Warning:
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Can I savely ignore that?

Comment: It's only because I was using a very old version of jquery in that jsfiddle. :)  try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/sbjaz/8/  I changed underscore, backbonejs, and jquery to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load your template in the `initialize` function. `this.model` doesn't exist at that point.

```
initialize: function() {
    this.ContentTpl = _.template( $('#slide-'+this.model.get('contentType')).html() );
}
```

However, this is still a bad pattern form backbone. I would inject it as an option.

```
var template = $('#slide-'+this.model.get('contentType')).html();
var appView = new AppView({model: app, ContentTpl: template });
...

// in your view
initialize: function(options) {
    this.ContentTpl = _.template( options.ContentTpl );
}
```

Comment: @FLuttenb it won't be global, but it will be an instance property. you can get to it with `render` with `this.ContentTpl`.

Comment: that's a bad idea because I have a lot of those templates and I wanna keep as much code in my backbone models as possible.

Comment: @FLuttenb a model isn't really ideal for storing templates.

Comment: so is it in general a good idea to create the templates outside of the backbone model/view and then just load it as an option? What if I have about 10 templates?

Comment: @FLuttenb also, the `model` property of `this` (the view) is an instance property.

Comment: @FLuttenb i generally used one template per view.

Comment: @FLuttenb if you want this to be configurable, it has to be a part of the instance of your view.